# How can I use data from a linked list generated in a tab for then use it in other tabs?

Tags: javascript, cookies, local-storage, session-storage, data-persistence

I have `tab1.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./js/list.js"></script>
    <title>Tab 1</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Here I fill the linked list with data</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="fillList();">Fill list</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="testThisTab();">Test to print the linked list generated in this tab</button>
    <a href="t2.html">Go to other page</a>
</body>
</html>
```

With the above code I have a button `Fill list`, and with this button I start the method `fillList` in my JS file, then I have a button `Test to print the linked list generated in this tab`, with this button I test that the linked list is working because I get in console:

```
List filled
5
1
6
3
2
```

and then I have a hyperlink to go to the `tab2.html`.

In `tab2.html` I have:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="./js/list.js"></script>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Here I want to use the linked list generated in the other view</h1>
    <button type="button" onclick="useOfMethosOfLinkedList();">print list data in console</button>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code I want to print the data of the linked list generated in `tab1.html`, but when I press the `print list data in console` button, I don´t get anything in console, maybe because when I turn the page the data of the linked list gets clear.

My javascript code name `list.js` is:

```
class Node {
    constructor(data) {
        this.data = data;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.size = 0;
    }

    empty() {
        return this.head == null;
    }

    add(data) {
        let aux = new Node(data);

        if (this.empty()) {
            this.head = aux
        } else {
            aux.next = this.head;
            this.head = aux;
        }
    }

    print() {
        let aux = this.head;
        while (aux != null) {
            console.log(aux.data);
            aux = aux.next;
        }
    }
}

let listl = new LinkedList();
function fillList() {
    listl.add("2");
    listl.add("3");
    listl.add("6");
    listl.add("1");
    listl.add("5");
    console.log("List filled");
}

function useOfMethodsOfLinkedList() {
    listl.print()
}

function testThisTab() {
    listl.print()
}
```

I were looking for information to save the data but it just appear information with API's, but I can´t use that, so if could help to find any solution I will be so grateful.

Comment: when you change page everything gets lost unless you save the state somehow.. but it's not clear why you cannot use the web storage api. Otherwise you need to serialize the object and send it to the server for storage and you have to implement the api also to retrieve the saved object. Another very weird approach could be to serialize the list in json and post it to the next page when you click the link to tab2.html. Give feedback if this last one approach could be interesting to you

Comment: Save the data to localStorage (or sessionStorage) and have the other tabs listen for a [storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event)